# Directional Offset of an noise wave texture

Tags: cycles-render-engine

When creating wood floors or other materials based on blender textures like noise wave ect., the Pattern that is created is clearly based on the same Seed and Point of Origin.

Example: A wooden floor where every plank has an original crack wooden pattern instead of what is currently standard a pattern were cracks are going visible from one plank into another.

What i would like to achieve is that i can break those up with an given amount.

So that you would get for a face with a diffrent pattern for every brick/plan/tile instead of what is now just one pattern for the whole face and then the bricks/tiles/planks painted above that.

And i dont want to create an object for every plank / brick. I know how that is achieved but that is also a pain because the array modifier doesent influence the seed so that wont work and copying by hand is just awful.

The desired effect is seen here at 3:30

[Substance YT Video about Wood material and Warp](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Y_s0Yr_OFCQ)

Comment: The Cycles Oblect Info Node > Random does produce a  new random number for each instance, if your planks are duplicates? Or are you looking to produce a random number per face of a single object / instance?

Comment: @Robin: As i Stated i dont want to create an object for every plank.
please look at the video to understand what im really after as it is clearly shown there.

I have found out that when i subdivide a face and then having a sort of mixend uv pattern then i get a random pattern from an texture for a face. But that is a painful way to do since one may have to edit the uvs by hand for that to work as expected. And it isnt as nice as in the video.

Comment: Sure.. I did watch the video.. whatever they're doing. it's face-wise. I was just checking .. The Object Info method works  with instances (sharing mesh data) and Duplis. (You're right, not with arrays). I was wondering whether Dupliverts might be an acceptable way through for you. Otherwise, some way would have to be given to Cycles to discriminate between faces .. something like tilting the normals slightly?

Comment: Face-wise.. [This script](https://github.com/Tlousky/blender_scripts/blob/master/random_material_assigners/random_material_assigner_per_face_new_features.py) might help, in combination with Object Info > Material Index? You could use duplicate materials with varying indices, to shift the mapping. Bit of a hack.

Comment: well waht they do is just shift the pixel data somewhat in a given mask or something.

Answer (score 1):

I found a way to wrap a noise texture using a brick texture. Actually, with at least three:

[image]

To create diferent brick textures I use very different location value on each node.

[Edit: you can use only one brick texture with black and white values, the 'difference' blend mode works well with the texture coordinate for example]

Next step is mix the texture coordinate with the result, you can play with the blend mode and the factor to get the result you want. then use this as normal input for the noise texture:

[image]

Then play around to get the desire result:

[image]